# Nested dictionary TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, key-value, nonetype

I have a dictionary containing questions.
The key is a number and the value is another dictionary. Here is an example of the structure:

```
    questions = {
    2313: {"question": "How much is 2+2", "answers": ["3", "4", "2", "1"], "correct": 2},
    4122: {"question": "What is the capital of France?", "answers": ["Lion", "Marseille", "Paris", "Montpellier"],
           "correct": 3}
}
```

I need to add more questions to the dictionary from a text file ('questions.txt') where the questions look like this:
0#What is the capital city of USA?#Washington DC#New York#Los Angeles#Detroit#1
After I open the file, I loop through all the questions and add them to the dictionary. I used a function from my protocol 'chatlib':

```
def split_data(data, expected_fields):

    splitted = data.split('#')
    if len(splitted) == expected_fields:
        return splitted
    else:
        return
```

So, for example, when I use it on the question before it will return it as a list that looks like this:
['0', 'What is the capital city of USA?', 'Washington DC', 'New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Detroit', '1']
I tried a lot of different ways to write the main code,

```
    list_new_questions = open("questions.txt").read().split('\n')
    for question in list_new_questions:
        questionlist = chatlib.split_data(question, 7)
        key = int(questionlist[0])
        questions[key] = {"question": "", "answers": [], "correct": 0}
        questions[key]["question"] = questionlist[1]
        questions[key]["answers"] = [questionlist[2], questionlist[3], questionlist[4], questionlist[5]]
        questions[key]["correct"] = int(questionlist[6])
```

but every time it returns an error (TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable) and says that the value of int(questionlist[0]) is None but I don't understand why. How can it be None? It is supposed to be the int value of the first element in the list, questionlist, which is always a number. Every time I print int(questionlist[0]) it always prints a number, so I don't understand why it says it's None.

Comment: You're making us guess exactly where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: `split_data` will return `None` when `len(splitted) == expected_fields:` is not true. Do you handle the case where `questionlist` can be `None`?

Comment: I suggest you add *print(data)* before *return* in your *split_data* function and you'll see that there are not the number of tokens you expected

Comment: no, but i know that specifically in my cases its not None because i gave it the correct number and it's always equal

Comment: File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/pythonProject8/server.py", line 100, in load_questions
    key = int(questionlist[0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 1):

In line 3 your function `chatlib.split_data(question, 7)` can return `None` if the `len(splitted)` is not equal to 7.

So when there aren't at least 7 fields, `questionlist` equals `None`. And then in line 4 you are trying to access index 0 of `None`.

An easy fix & restructure would be something like:

```py
def split_data(data):
    # validate data here
    splitted = data.split("#")
    # validate splitted here if you need to
    return splitted


list_new_questions = open("questions.txt").read().split("\n")
for question in list_new_questions:
    questionlist = chatlib.split_data(question)
    # do your validation here
    if len(questionlist) == 7:
        # try except maybe if you are unsure about the data split you get
        key = int(questionlist[0])
        questions[key] = {
            "question": questionlist[1], 
            "answers": questionlist[2:6], 
            "correct": int(questionlist[6)
        }
    else: 
        print("Invalid question format")
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the error message:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Subscript notation is when you use square brackets like so: `X[Y]`. On the line that raises the exception, the only place where that happens is `questionlist[0]`. You cannot subscribe or index `None` because what would `None[0]` even mean? So that tells you that `questionlist` is `None`.

We can figure out why that is the case by looking at the previous line,

`questionlist = chatlib.split_data(question, 7)`

So what does `split_data` return?

Either `return splitted`, which is a list of string or `return`, which is the same as `return None`. So we know the latter has to be have happened, which means you've come across a line with an unexpected number of `#`s.

This could have happened because 1) there is a typo somewhere, because 2) you have an empty line in the file, or because 3) the file ends with a newline (automatically inserted by some editors).

The next question is, what do you want to happen in those cases? If you just want to ignore any non-matching line, Yash's solution will help you.

But I think while allowing 3 is definitely good and 2 is probably good for your use-case as well, I don't think you should want to just carry on like nothing's wrong in the case of 1. If there's a typo, I think you want your program to complain loudly... but maybe with a more useful error message.

You could do this without modifying `split_data` at all. Here's a possible solution:

```
    list_new_questions = open("questions.txt").read().split('\n')
    for question in list_new_questions:
        if question.strip() == '':
            # Ignore lines with only whitespace
            continue
        questionlist = chatlib.split_data(question, 7)
        if questionlist is None:
            # Not the right number of fields!
            raise Exception(f"Invalid question format: {question!r}")
        key, question, *answers, correct = questionlist
        questions[int(key)] = {"question": question, "answers": answers, "correct": int(correct)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your split_data function can return a None value if the actual fields is != expected_fields.

You can do it like below which can also account for if you start providing more answers.

This also removes the need for the split_data function as it can be done as part of the loop.

```
with open("questions.txt") as f:
    new_questions = f.readlines()

    for q in new_questions:
        q = q.split("#")
        if len(q) == 7:
            questions[int(q[0])] = {
                "question": q[1],
                "answers": q[2:-1],
                "correct": int(q[-1])}
        else:
            print(f"Invalid Data {q}")
```

If you wanted to provide more or less than 4 answers you could do something like below which only assumes the id is the first field, question is the second and answer is the last

```
for q in new_questions:
    q = q.split("#")
    try:
        questions[int(q[0])] = {
            "question": q[1],
            "answers": q[2:-1],
            "correct": int(q[-1])}
    except IndexError:
        print(f"Invalid data {q}")
```

Comment: If `questions.txt` contains an empty line, the second one will raise an `IndexError`!  (Also, minor nitpick, but instead of `q[len(q) - 1]` it's more Pythonic to use `q[-1]`)